# how to redirect a 404 page not found in OpenCart using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, opencart

on my .htaccess:

I tried to redirect a 404 page **about_us** page to **about-us** page using line code below

```
redirect 301 /about_us http://www.example.com/about-us
```

but when I tried to load to the browser for about-us page is redirect to this page to

`http://www.example.com/about-us?_route_=about_us` but still the page is in 404 error

here is my .htaccess rule

```
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
#RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you have more rules in your .htaccess? If yes then post them here in question.

Comment: maybe its because of https version of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `redirect` rule with `mod_rewrite` rules. Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about_us/?$ http://www.example.com/about-us [L,NC,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
#RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old browser cache**.